# Noetherian property in the small fppf site of an algebraic stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X \longrightarrow Y$ be a flat and finitely presented morphism where $X$ is a scheme and $Y$ is a Noetherian (or locally Noetherian) algebraic stack, then will this imply $X$ is also Noetherian (or locally Noetherian)?  I am using here the definition of a Noetherian stack as in Stacks Project which states that $Y$ is a Noetherian algebraic stack if for any affine scheme $U$ and any smooth morphism $U \xrightarrow{smooth} Y$, $U$ is Noetherian.

If not, can someone give me an explicit example?

P.S: I have posted this in Math Stack Exchange but didn't get a reply and so I have reposted it here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a ring $R$, being Noetherian can be checked after faithful base change, $R\to S$, in the following sense. For a set $\{J_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ of ideals of $R$, if the associated set of ideals$\{J_\alpha S\}_{\alpha \in A}$ has a maximal element $J_\beta S$, then also $J_\beta$ is a maximal element of the original set.  Indeed, suppose that $J_\beta \subset J_\alpha$ is a proper inclusion, i.e., $J_\alpha/J_\beta$ is nonzero. Since $S$ is faithful, also $J_\alpha S/J_\beta S$ is nonzero.

Comment: The answer is yes even if $X\to Y$ is not flat and $X$ is not a scheme. This follows from http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04YF (1) $\Leftrightarrow$ (2): X is locally noetherian iff there exists a smooth surjective map $U\to X$ where U is a locally noetherian scheme.

Comment: For an algebraic stack, there is a smooth, faithfully flat morphism $U\to Y$ from an affine scheme $U$ to the stack $Y$.  Thus, also $X\times_Y U \to X$ is smooth and faithfully flat.  By my previous comment, it suffices to check that $X\times_Y U$ is Noetherian.

Comment: @Marc Hoyois: I don't see how is that true without any condition! For any non Noetherian ring $A$, consider the morphism $Spec(A) \longrightarrow Spec(k)$ where $k$ is a field. $Spec(k)$ is certainly Noetherian but $Spec(A)$ is not.

Comment: I guess I must mention this simple example was pointed out to me in stackexchange.

Comment: @Jason Starr: Thanks! Just to clarify: Since $X \times_{Y}U$ is an algebraic space (by the definition of an algebraic stack), we can consider the affine scheme from where there exists an etale surjection on the algebraic space and then show that this affine scheme is Noetherian. Now using your first comment the argument can be completed. I think this is what you meant. I wrote this just to be sure, since I am a beginner in algebraic stacks.

Comment: @Sam $X\to Y$ is still finitely presented.

Comment: @MarcHoyois: Ok...then it's fine.